# Lambda not equal on join

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, .net-4.5

Table 1 called Category contains 70 records
Table 2 called FilterCategorys contains 0 records (currently).

my lambda join, I want to pull only records that don't match, so in this case I expect to get 70 records back.  Here's my incorrect Lambda:

```
var filteredList = categorys
            .Join(filterCategorys,
                x => x.Id,
                y => y.CategoryId,
                (x, y) => new { catgeory = x, filter = y })
            .Where(xy => xy.catgeory.Id != xy.filter.CategoryId)
            .Select(xy => new Category()
                        {
                            Name = xy.catgeory.Name,
                            Id = xy.catgeory.Id,
                            ParentCategoryId = xy.catgeory.ParentCategoryId
                        })
            .ToList();
```

Whats the correct syntax I need here?

Comment: What you are doing does return what is common match with Id and CategoryId and what you want is opposite of it.

Comment: yes, I thought the != would do what i need, ive also looks at ".Contains()" and "Except()"

Comment: Try using except method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in purely lambda:

```
var match = categorys.Join(filterCategorys, x => x.Id, y => y.CategoryId, (x, y) => new { Id = x.Id });
var filteredList = categorys.Where(x => !match.Contains(new {Id = x.Id}));
```

I haven't measured the performance of this, but for 70 records, optimization is not an issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm going to select yours as the answer as it still uses joins in the lambda expression,  using my answer currently, but as you said no idea if theirs a performance loss/gain with iether.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you have a requirement of using lambdas (rather than query syntax), but I prefer query syntax for statements that have outer joins.

This should be equivalent:

```
var filteredList = (
    from c in Categorys 
    join fc in FilterCategorys on c.Id equals fc.CategoryId into outer
    from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new 
    {
        Category = new Category 
        {
            Name = c.Name, 
            Id = c.Id, 
            ParentCategoryId = c.ParentCategoryId
        },
        Exists = (o != null)
    })
    .Where(c => !c.Exists)
    .Select(c => c.Category);
```

Comment: sorry in you select Where has this "Exists" come from?

Comment: @lemunk, Yeah, sorry, I originally did it with anonymous types.  I updated the answer so that it compiles correctly...

Answer (score 1):

Well I came up with a solution that takes away the need for the join.

```
var currentIds = filterCategorys.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
var filteredList = categorys.Where(x => !currentIds.Contains(x.Id));
```

very similar to @Zoff Dino answer, not sure about performance, maybe someone would like to check.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var categories= ...
var filteredCategories=...
var allExceptFiltered = categories.Except(filteredCategories, new CategoryComparer()).ToList();
```

If you don't provide a custom Comparer that framework has no way of knowing that 2 Category objects are the same(even if they have the same ID),it just thinks that they are different objects (it checks for reference equality )

so you must add this class to your project:

```
public class CategoryComparer: IEqualityComparer<Category>
{
    public bool Equals(Category x, Category y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if (x == null)
            return false;

        if (y == null)
            return false;

        return x.CategoryId.GetHashCode() == y.CategoryId.GetHashCode();

    }

    public int GetHashCode(Category obj)
    {
        return obj.CategoryId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**update**

Also check out Wyatt Earp's answer,it is very useful to know how to do an outer join

**update 2**
Your problem is the Join method.
The Where clause is "called" after the join.so after you have joined the listed based on the ID you select those which have different IDs,that's why you get no resuts

Comment: not sure i follow what you mean, nor understand the need for the code.  Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @lemunk the need for what code exactly?The comparer?

Comment: yes all i need to do is get all records that don't exist in the filteredCategory table, so im not sure why im adding a custom class comparer to achieve this

Comment: I explained it before the class declaration...(if you don't provide a custom...)

Comment: yes but in the lambda expression im comparing the ID property's of my tables, not the objects themselves, hence why i dont understand why i need a comparer?

Comment: @lemunk I updated my answer,check the update 2 comment

Answer (score 0):

Could you draw bracket and it should work.
....Where(xy => **(xy.catgeory.Id != xy.filter.CategoryId)**)